# Best way to post to twitter via Java Application

Tags: java, twitter

In my applications, I'll like to update a twitter account when some event occurs. Just update status, nothing more.
So, I think that is heavy use something like twitter4j just to do this.

What do you think about? Should I use twitter4j or other API, or do a "low level" code manually?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

twittter4j is a good one, I'm using it and it works fine.
If you are using spring, you can also easily use spring-social-twtitter.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use `twitter4j`